# Does protobuf-net support named tuples?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

Does protobuf-net support the serialisation of [named tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#tuples)?

eg

```
 [ProtoMember(1)]
 protected readonly SortedDictionary<double, (double Bid, double Ask, double Open, double High, double Low, double Close, int Volume, int OpenInt)> FuturesCurveData;
```

Comment: Well it would be rather handy to know before I write a whole class around it. The documentation does not say.

Comment: @screig "The documentation does not say" - it is impossible to cover every conceivable scenario, but : *the release notes do mention it* - see v2.2.0 http://mgravell.github.io/protobuf-net/releasenotes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Partly yes, partly no".

protobuf-net has no *specific knowledge* of named tuples, and [the names are not available to library code](http://blog.marcgravell.com/2017/04/exploring-tuples-as-library-author.html), but from v2.2.0 onwards, protobuf-net *is able* to infer a contract for `ValueTuple<...>` types, essentially treating it as a positional type - so `Bid` would be field 1, `Ask` would be field 2, etc. Some code like `GetProto<T>` will *not* produce the results you expect (since a: it can't see the names, and b: the shape gets very odd for large tuples), and you won't be able to control fine-grained serialization details (`DataFormat`, etc), but: it should work.

The following works fine:

```
using ProtoBuf;
using System.Collections.Generic;

static class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var obj = new MyType { FuturesCurveData = {
                { 1.0, (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8) },
                { 2.0, (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9) },
            } };
        var clone = Serializer.DeepClone(obj);
        foreach(var pair in clone.FuturesCurveData)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine($"{pair.Key}: {pair.Value}");
        }
    }
}
[ProtoContract]
class MyType
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public SortedDictionary<double, (double Bid, double Ask, double Open, double High, double Low, double Close, int Volume, int OpenInt)> FuturesCurveData { get; } =
    new SortedDictionary<double, (double Bid, double Ask, double Open, double High, double Low, double Close, int Volume, int OpenInt)>();
}
```

output:

```
1: (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
2: (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

And here's what `GetProto<MyType>()` produces - not quite such a success:

```
syntax = "proto2";
package System;

message KeyValuePair_Double_ValueTuple_Double_Double_Double_Double_Double_Double_Int32_ValueTuple_Int32 {
   optional double Key = 1;
   optional ValueTuple_Double_Double_Double_Double_Double_Double_Int32_ValueTuple_Int32 Value = 2;
}
message MyType {
   repeated KeyValuePair_Double_ValueTuple_Double_Double_Double_Double_Double_Double_Int32_ValueTuple_Int32 FuturesCurveData = 1;
}
message ValueTuple_Double_Double_Double_Double_Double_Double_Int32_ValueTuple_Int32 {
   optional double Item1 = 1;
   optional double Item2 = 2;
   optional double Item3 = 3;
   optional double Item4 = 4;
   optional double Item5 = 5;
   optional double Item6 = 6;
   optional int32 Item7 = 7;
   optional ValueTuple_Int32 Rest = 8;
}
message ValueTuple_Int32 {
   optional int32 Item1 = 1;
}
```

As a side note, it *should* work as a `map<,>` if the key type was `int` or `string`, but it appears to have hit a bug, which [I have logged](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/issues/285).